# Spring-Security-Ldap - How to report Locked Account

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I have a properly working Spring-LDAP instance configured against ApacheDS.

Pretty vanilla security context:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-context-mapper-ref="detailsMapper"
        user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people" user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
        group-search-base="ou=groups" group-search-filter="member={0}">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When an account gets locked, I see in the debug where the lock is acknowledged:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator - Failed to bind as uid=lorin,ou=people: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: account will remain locked till Sun Jun 07 22:17:01 EDT 2015]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: account will remain locked till Sun Jun 07 22:17:01 EDT 2015]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Login credentials not found
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@521758c5
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

But by the time the exception makes it back to my failure handler the exception is strictly a BadCredentialsException with nothing more than my configured messages statement.

```
public abstract class AbstractLockDetectingAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory .getLogger(AbstractLockDetectingAuthenticationFailureHandler.class);

final protected static Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

@Resource(name="messageSource")
private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messages;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

    exception.printStackTrace();

    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
}
```

*How can I report a locked account vs. a bad password without having to customize a class and subsequently throw myself in to configuration hell for a single message?*

(And yes, I know its bad form to report locked v. bad password as it leaks security ... insistent customer)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to override the method "handleBindException" inside BindAuthenticator with the following code to throw specific exceptions:

```
protected void handleBindException(String userDn, String username, Throwable cause) {
    super.handleBindException(userDn, username, cause);
    //handle account locked
    if (cause.getMessage().contains("account was permanently locked"))
    {
        throw new LockedException(messages.getMessage(
                "LdapAuthenticationProvider.locked", "User account is locked"), cause);
    }
    //second example: handle password lifetime reached
    if (cause.getMessage().contains("password end time reached"))
    {
        throw new AccountExpiredException(messages.getMessage(
                "LdapAuthenticationProvider.expired", "User account has expired"),
                cause);
    }
}
```

How to override the BindAuthenticator depends mainly on your spring version and if you're using spring-boot. Your code looks like your're using vanilla spring.

As defining your own authenticationprovider instead of using the xml ldap-authentication-provider-Tag bean can be quite cumbersome (because of all the child beans that need to be defined manually then and the) I recommend to call LdapAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticator() somewhere in your initalization to override the Authenticator.